# Give application/user access to USB device

Tags: linux, usb, permissions, mono-framework, libusb

I have a Mono application running on Raspbian that uses a certain USB device through libusb. If I start the application normally it fails to open the device. If I start the application as root (or through sudo) the application successfully opens the device.

How can I give the application or user the proper permissions for the USB device so that the application doesn't have to be started as root?

Answer (score 1):

To give a specific group access to a USB device you have to add a rule to `udev` in `/etc/udev/rules.d/`. I added a file called `50-MyDevice.rules` that contains this line:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTRS{idVendor}=="abcd",ATTRS{idProduct}=="1234",MODE="0660",GROUP="mygroup",SYMLINK+="mydevice%n"
```

Where I have replaced the values after *idVendor* and *idProduct* with the USB device's VID and PID. Pay special attention to the number of equal signs after each parameter!

After this I rebooted linux.

Now, every time I plug in the USB device (or if I plug in several of the same device) I get a symlink called `/dev/mydevice1` or `/dev/mydevice2`. This is a symlink pointing to `/dev/bus/usb/001/001` (or in the second case `/dev/bus/usb/001/002`). The targets of these symlinks have the the proper mode and group permissions defined in the rules file.